# google-bigquery format date as mm/dd/yyyy in query results

Tags: sql, date, format, google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery SQL to generate a report.  The standard Bigquery date format is yyyy-mm-dd, but I want it to be formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

Is there a way via Bigquery SQL to convert the date format on SELECT?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT 
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC("2016-10-20", "%m/%d/%Y"),   
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(CURRENT_DATE(), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

In BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", DATE "2016-10-20"), 
  FORMAT_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", CURRENT_DATE())
```

Also useful [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: You may need to use FORMAT_TIMESTAMP in the standard SQL example if the OP has a timestamp (not date) column.